# Unknown meaning on ring (Characters identified: 东京喰种)

Tags: translation, character-identification

need to know meaning on this ring, was given to me by someone and could have significant meaning in a personal matter!! Please help

[image: 东京喰种 on a ring]

Comment: This is the name of a Japanese anime. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Ghoul

Comment: Is your "someone" a Japanese teenager? Here's the series of manga https://www.yhdmp.com/showp/14114.html  Sorry that it doesn't turn out to be the "significant meaning in a personal matter!!" that your are looking for; I certainly hope not as the manga is about demons and such roaming around Tokyo.

Answer (score 1):

just the name of a Japanese anime, meaning Tokyo Ghoul [東京喰種](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Ghoul)